# image not ocuppying whole space in div

Tags: html, css

what do i do if i put the  tag inside a div which has, say 354x300 px something, rough estimate, and the src of that  tag has a px of 1.6k x 1.2k? The problem is that there is a space below the image, i doesn't occupy the whole space, i don't know what happen the image is already big enough i thought its gonna re-size itself to what is the size of the div where the img tag is located.

```
<div class="myClass">
     <img src="theVeryBigImage.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Above is my code for that part which results on this part, see image below

[image]

As you can see, that image has a size of 1600x1200 px but still it doesn't occupy the whole space, it leaves a whitespace (Blank space) below

Comment: could you provide the live link if possible ?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't load completely :D Use "Inspect Element" to see what corresponds to the white space below and remove it. Or if part of the image is missing you'll be able to see what's hiding it

Comment: nope its working, its just that it resizes itself, already answered below all are correct except with the negative up vote :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some default css may be setting image height.

Try

```
.myClass { height: /* some height */; }
.myClass img{ height:100% ; }
```

Comment: question: the image is kinda stretched, i think this is normal considering the size of the div and the size of the actual image, but hmmm is this normal?

Comment: The trend is to fix size of wrapper div and set the image size to 100%, so that even with different image sizes whole page layout remains stable.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
.myClass  img{display:block ;height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no padding and no margin between `div` and `img`

```
.myClass { margin:0; padding: 0; width: auto; height: auto; }
.myClass img { margin:0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: does this prevent stretching of image, but i do think the current image is normal :D